# The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '5.0.0' was not found

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-5

Hi I create one WPF application using .Net 5.0 . It is working fine in my dev system .

But when i try to copy and run bin folder to my windows 7 system , It is giving below error :

> The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.

[image]

[image]

But still getting error .

**Update :**

But Self contained package working fine .
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This condition is caused by the fact that your other machine may not have the required .NET 5.0.7 Desktop runtime to run your .NET 5.0 WPF app.

On the [official page to download .NET 5.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0), each SDK and related runtime version has its own notes. If you only install .NET 5.0 runtime, it won't install the related .NET 5.0 Desktop runtime to support WPF and Windows Forms.

For example:
[image: .NET 5.0.7 Runtime download note]

That picture shows that you still have to install .NET 5.0.7 Desktop Runtime manually after you install .NET 5.0.7 runtime.

Therefore to fix your problem, you have to install .NET 5.0.7 Desktop Runtime, not just installing .NET 5.0.7 Runtime.

Comment: thanks this work ..
my bad I installed first link (console app only ) , now installed windows app framework and working fine .